# How do I override both the before and after pseudo classes on a radio button label

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the radio button properly after having added an input to the label.  The input is pushing the text down but the radio button is staying put, so that causes a misalignment as you can see in this screenshot.

[image]

This is my HTML

```
  <table class=standardform style='margin-top:20px'>
  <tr><td><input type=radio name=newbookingdatetype value='date' class=newbookingdatetype id=newbookingdatetype-date checked>&nbsp;<label for=newbookingdatetype-date>One Time</label></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type=radio name=newbookingdatetype value='weekday' class=newbookingdatetype id=newbookingdatetype-recurring>&nbsp;<label for=newbookingdatetype-recurring id=recurringlabel>Recurring every <input type=number id=newbookingrecurringweeks value='6' class=integer style='width:50px;text-align:center' disabled> weeks</label></td></tr>
  </table>
```

The radio button is obviously not native, but is rendered using some fancy css with before and after pseudo classes.  So to try to compensate for this I'm trying to manipulate the before and after of the label element.

I've given the label for the second radio button an ID and added the following CSS

```
<style type=text/css>

#recurringlabel:before{top:5px};
#recurringlabel:after{top:8px};

</style>
```

The default for "before" is top:0px and for "after" it's top:3px, so I'm basically just trying to bump the whole thing down by five pixels.

In Chrome developer tools if I change those values then it lines up properly, but in real life only the first rule is taking effect.  So the before class is setting the top property to 5px but the after class is completely ignoring the top:8px.

So now it looks like this when it's unchecked

[image]

But like this when it's checked

[image]

If I reverse the style settings like so...

```
<style type=text/css>

#recurringlabel:after{top:8px};
#recurringlabel:before{top:5px};

</style>
```

Then only the "after" setting takes effect, but the "before" setting is ignored.

[image]

In other words, the second setting is always ignored.  Why is that?  And is there a better way for me to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: try using !important and obviously it is not recommended.

Comment: Could it be a specificity issue? Is the label referred to elsewhere as, for instance, .standardform #recurringlabel?

Comment: I did a search for "recurringlabel" in my project and it's not found anywhere else, but to be doubly sure I just added an x to the end of the id and I still had the same problem.

Comment: I tried adding !important but that also didn't help.  I should add that the #recurringlabel:after css class does not even appear in chrome developer tools when I load my page, so the browser is not even seeing it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your semi-colons are misplaced:

```
<style type=text/css>

#recurringlabel:after{top:8px};
#recurringlabel:before{top:5px};

</style>
```

Should be (Added some additional good formatting which makes these problems easier to spot)

```
<style type=text/css>

#recurringlabel:after{
   top:8px;
}
#recurringlabel:before{
   top:5px;
}

</style>
```

On another note, if the button is using / can be made to use `display: inline-block;` for either itself or its parent you can use `vertical-align` to get what you want.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Comment: Funny how you can stare at something for hours and not see the obvious.  :-)